# Specify multiple scopes in PayPal RequestPermission API

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

Looking at the [RequestPermissions API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_PermissionsRequestPermissionsAPI), it says that the scope is supposed to be a string.  However, I have been unsuccessful in finding out how to specify more than one scope (specifically EXPRESS_CHECKOUT and REFUND).  Comma-separated, semi-colon, and even using their NVP list syntax didn't work.  A CURL sample would be greatly appreciated.

Comma-separated example...

```
curl -s --insecure -H 
"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: API_USERNAME" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: API_PASSWORD" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: API_SIGNATURE" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" 
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions -d 
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&scope=EXPRESS_CHECKOUT,REFUND&callback=http://my/callback"
```

When I make that request, I get back "Invalid request parameter scope with value EXPRESS_CHECKOUT,REFUND"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok.  Found the answer randomly.  The scope variables must be set using "scope(0)=SCOPE_1&scope(1)=SCOPE_2..."

So, the cURL request would look like this...

```
curl -s --insecure -H 
"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: API_USERNAME" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: API_PASSWORD" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: API_SIGNATURE" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" 
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions -d 
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&scope(0)=EXPRESS_CHECKOUT&scope(1)=REFUND&callback=http://my/callback"
```

Comment: Dude, what the heck. PayPal's apis, and documentation are such garbage. Thank you for posting this. If you are in Seattle, I owe you a beer.

Comment: Sigh! PayPal api gives such a headache!! Thanks for this! +1

Comment: @mikesir87 : I am owner of my ecommerce website. I have many sellers added there. I am asking that if i put my app credentials (username, password, signature, app id) there and run this script, will this grant the permission from sellers too ? To make an api call like refund api we need permission from sellers too. So will this script grant the permissions from all the sellers including me ?

Comment: In this script to whom we are requesting to grant permission for ?

Comment: In addition if that can help someone with php to supply multiple scopes it must be an array. Example : $data = array("scope" => array("EXPRESS_CHECKOUT","EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"),"callback" => "http://url/success.html","requestEnvelope" => array ("errorLanguage" => "en_US" ) );
    $payload = json_encode($data);

Answer (score 3):

If you're using their JSON API, scope can be an array.